# Can I use the PHP SOAP library in PHP 5.1.1?

Tags: php, soap-client

I have developed a PHP site with PHP 5.3, and would like to deploy it to a server running PHP 5.1.1. My site depends **heavily** on the PHP SOAP library, since pretty much everything that isn't a presentation task is done by a Web Service. Does PHP 5.1.1 support the SOAP library? Apparently, it doesn't come with the default PHP installation, so, where could I download it?

Comment: Have you checked [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/soap.installation.php)?

Comment: There is no such a thing as PHP documentation, unless I'm supposed to take "Contributed Notes" as documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before answering your question, I want to mention that you really should upgrade (or convince whoever is in charge) to 5.3.

That said, soap is available, but you must compile with `--enable-soap`. If you're on a system that uses a package manager, you may try `apt-get install php-soap`, `yum install php-soap`, etc. If you're on windows, you may have to download `php_soap.dll`.

Answer (score 2):

SOAP should be able to run on any version of PHP 5. However, it's important to note that prior to PHP 5.2.9 the SOAP extension is only capable of understanding WSDL 1.0 and 1.1 formats.

To enable SOAP support, configure PHP with `--enable-soap`.

Comment: The Web Service I am consuming is a fairly ordinary ASP.NET Web Service (I know, I have written it as well). What version of SOAP does ASP.NET support?

Comment: @Eduardo No idea, I'm a PHP guy.